# How to show that the method to create two correlated random numbers is correct?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I would like to understand how I can show that the method to create two normally distributed random numbers given as an [answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/114987/128758) is correct.

Given independent $X_1$ and $X_2$ normally distributed with mean zero and variance 1, one can get a randomvariable with correlation $\mathbb{E}[X_1 X_3] =\rho$ by setting 
$$
X_3=\rho X_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}X_2.
$$

Comment: $X_1$ and $X_2$ should be independent, then you would have $\Bbb E[X_1X_2]=0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Question solved. Should I delete it?

Comment: In principle this is not a chat but a community, meaning that questions and answers are there to be seen by anyone and possibly commented or improved. However, as it was only a point you skipped in the formulation of your problem, this could be considered as not very relevant for other people. Up to you. And welcome in here, by the way.,

Comment: @V.Rossetto thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1 X_3] = \mathbb{E}[X_1 (\rho X_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}X_2]$$
$$ = \mathbb{E}[\rho X_1^2 +\sqrt{1-\rho^2}X_1X_2] $$
$$ = \rho\mathbb{E}[ X_1^2] +\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2] $$
Here I can [use the relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99027/128758) $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\text{Var}(X)+(\mathbb{E}[X])^2$ to get
$$=\rho + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2].$$
Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent we have $\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2]=0$, which leads to the desired result
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1 X_3]=\rho$$